# Get FileVersionInfo for executable in PATH environment variable without knowing full filepath

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to do something like this:

```
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(SomeFile.exe);
```

...But I don't know the full filepath of SomeFile.exe.  I *do* know that it will be in the Windows PATH or in the current directory where my code is running from, but it's possible that there could be more than one copy of SomeFile.exe on the system.  If I use the Process class to launch SomeFile.exe, I am able to simply do this:

```
Process.StartInfo.FileName = SomeFile.exe;
Process.Start();
```

I need a way to get the FileVersionInfo of the same SomeFile.exe that would be launched with Process.Start() without having to manually search through the Windows PATH locations and the current directory.  While it would be possible to do a manual search, it doesn't solve the issue of informing me which SomeFile.exe Windows will select to execute if no filepath is specified in the Process.StartInfo.FileName  It's important that I don't get the FileVersionInfo of a different SomeFile.exe.

Comment: One sure way to do it is [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) as [`CREATE_SUSPENDED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) then use the [`HPROCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information) to retrieve the path and version info. Not entirely straightforward in C#, though.

Comment: `Path.GetFullPath`?

Comment: @dxiv thx for the suggestion... I will look into creating it suspended, but I might even be able to just create it not-suspended and use Process.MainModule.FileName and then kill it.  It's kinda kludgy but it might be good enough for my needs here, though still open to other ideas if anyone else reads this. Was hoping for a more elegant/efficient method.